# Using OpenCV in Windows Form

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been playing about with OpenCV in some console applications recently to try and get the hand of it, everything went well.

But today i have tried to use it in a windows form on visual C++ 2010...I have set up all the file linkage as you would if using a console application. But it does not want to work, i keep getting this error:

error C3821: '_atexit_m_appdomain': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function

warning C4793: '`anonymous namespace'::CV_XADD' : function compiled as native :
1>      Inline native assembly not supported in managed code

well actually i have 30 errors like this lol

Has anyone here ever used OCV in a windows form before or anything similar who could lend me a hand i'm totally lost. I have also tried changing the "Common Runtime Support" in properties and none of the options seem to help either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since Winforms uses C++/CLI, You need something like [EMGU OpenCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/OpenCV) which is a managed wrapper around the OpenCV library.